# Warning simplexml_load_file parser error from youtube

Tags: xml-parsing, youtube, youtube-api, simplexml, http-status-code-403

I get this error (occasionally) when I'm searching videos in youtube script, other times it just works, but then the problem appears again. Can someone help me to fix this issue?

Error Message:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?vq=music&orderby=relevance&max-results=10&start-index=201&lr=en): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in /home/website/public_html/search.php on line 119 

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?vq=music&orderby=relevance&max-results=10&start-index=201&lr=en" in /home/website/public_html/search.php on line 119

Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object in /home/website/public_html/search.php on line 122
```

Line 119:

```
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
```

Line 122:

```
$counts = $sxml->children('http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/');
```

Comment: Youtube is restricting your automated requests, that's why "occasionally" the script doesn't work... use youtube api instead - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Comment: Fixed with api-key. Thanks @Tuga!

Comment: always glad to help, if possible, mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube is restricting your automated requests, that's why "occasionally" the script doesn't work... use [youtube api](http://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) instead.